# What is this "Schreier factor function"?

Tags: group-theory, functions

I'm now reading the paper "Automorphisms of Group Extensions" by C. Wells [Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 1971]. There is a paragraph mentions about the **Schreier factor function** $\mu\colon\Pi^2\to G$ ($\Pi$ and $G$ are groups) satisfying the following relations:

$\mu(x,yz)+\mu(y,z)=\mu(xy,z)+\mu(x,y)z$ where $x,y,z\in\Pi$, and

$(ax)y=[a(xy)]^{\mu(x,y)}=-\mu(x,y)+a(xy)+\mu(x,y)$ where $a\in G$, $x,y\in\Pi$.

I tried to find more properties of this function but I found nothing.

Could anyone provide me the full definition and properties of this fuction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing out some key information! Specifically, you are missing out the fact that there is the following short exact sequence. $$1\rightarrow G\rightarrow E\rightarrow\Pi\rightarrow 1$$
($(G, E, \Pi)$ is the notation Wells uses - I would lean towards $(N, G, Q)$, but anyway...). You are also missing certain bits of notation. I will explain the notation below when I come to them. Now, I am unsure of any additional properties (I have written a short bit on the properties you have), but I can tell you the definition. Indeed, it is in Wells' paper, but is slightly disguised (that is, it doesn't say "Definiton:...").

Fix a transversal $T$ for $\Pi=E/G$, so $T:\Pi\rightarrow E$. Now, Wells writes $+$ for multiplication in $G$ and $E$ but I shall use $\times$ (because generally $+$ implies commutative, but that is not the case here). I will use $\cdot$ for multiplication in $\Pi$.

Now, if $h\in E$ then it can be written as $h=T(x)\times a$ for some $x\in \Pi$ and some $a\in G$, simply because $G$ is normal. Suppose $h, k\in E$, then $h\times k$ has this form also, so
$$\begin{align*}
h\times k
&=(T(x)\times a)\times (T(y)\times b)\\
&=T(z)\times c
\end{align*}$$
So, the question is "What are $z$ and $c$?" Well, $z=xy$ (again, because $G$ is normal). However, from the information we have we cannot determine $c$ (in general). This is where the Schreier Factor Function comes in. It is precisely the function such that
$$\begin{align*}
(T(x)\times a)\times (T(y)\times b)
&=T(x)\times T(y)\times T(y)^{-1}\times a\times T(y)\times b\\
&=T(x\cdot y)\times\mu(x, y)\times a^{T(y)}\times b
\end{align*}$$
Note that $a^{T(y)}:=T(y)^{-1}\times a\times T(y)\in G$ as, once again, $G$ is normal in $E$.

> In summary, $\mu(x, y)$ is the function $\mu: \Pi\times\Pi\rightarrow G$ such that $$T(x)\times T(y)=T(x\cdot y)\times \mu(x, y)$$ in $E$, where $T$ is a transversal function for $\Pi\cong E/G$.

Note that the transversal function $T$ matters, that is, $\mu$ is dependent on $T$. For example, take $E=\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and take $G=\langle 2\rangle$, then $\Pi=\{0+G, 1+G\}$. We could take the transversal function to be the function $T_a$ such that $T_a(0+G)=0$ and $T_a(1+G)=1$ or to be the function $T_b$ such that $T_b(0+G)=2$ and $T_b(1+G)=1$ (note that there are many more choices!). Then
$$\begin{align*}
1=0+1&=T_a(0+G)+T_a(1+G)\\
&=T_a(1+G)+\mu_a(0+G, 1+G)\\
&=1+\mu_a(0+G, 1+G)\\
\end{align*}$$
and so $\mu_a(0+G, 1+G)=0$. On the other hand,
$$\begin{align*}
3=2+1&=T_b(0+G)+T_b(1+G)\\
&=T_b(1+G)+\mu_b(0+G, 1+G)\\
&=1+\mu_b(0+G, 1+G)
\end{align*}$$
and so $\mu_b(0+G, 1+G)=2$. Therefore, $\mu_a\neq\mu_b$.

Finally, I should say something about the properties you have written. Specifically, concatenation is *not* multiplication. Rather, when Wells writes $ax$ for $a\in G$, $x\in\Pi$, this is shorthand for $T(x)^{-1}\times a\times T(x)$, so when you write $\mu(x, y)z$ this is actually $T(z)^{-1}\times\mu(x, y)\times T(z)\in G$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.

In paper, it didn't say that $G$ is normal in $E$. I think this condition is needless, though.

Comment: @pingz Normality is implicit as the sequence is [*exact*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence). Do you think the condition is needless for what Wells is doing, or for the definition of the Schreier Factor Function? Without normality, nothing Wells does makes sense (although you might be able to force some of it through if you try *really* hard). This is because without normality then $\Pi$ would no longer be a group. Perhaps normality is not essential to the definition of the Schreier Factor Function. That is perhaps a nice exercise.